# Python 3 - Global Variables with while loops

Tags: python, variables, while-loop, global

I have been trying to write a Python script that uses global variables.
I am getting what seems to be unexpected results in my code.
Instead of dumping all the code here, I have created a small piece of code to show what I'm seeing.

```
def func1():
    global aaa
    aaa = 1

def func2():
    while aaa < 5:
        print(aaa)
        aaa += 1

func1()
func2()
```

I am expecting to get,

```
1
2
3
4
```

What I get instead is,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 11, in <module>
    func2()
  File "test2.py", line 6, in func2
    while aaa < 5:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'aaa' referenced before assignment
```

If I change func2 to remove the while loop & just print the aaa variable, it works fine, so the global variable is accessible.

```
def func1():
    global aaa
    aaa = 1

def func2():
    print(aaa)

func1()
func2()
```

Running it produces,

```
1
```

If I set the aaa value at the top of func2 it also works.

```
def func1():
    global aaa
    aaa = 1

def func2():
    aaa = 1
    while aaa < 5:
        print(aaa)
        aaa += 1

func1()
func2()
```

Which results in,

```
1
2
3
4
```

I have experience with Perl, but am new to Python.
Is there something that I'm missing here?

Comment: https://trinket.io/python3/1c5055c6e7

Comment: How come you didn't declare `global aaa` also in `func2()`? I think that might fix it. Plus you have to ensure `aaa` is set to some value before you try to read access it. @Paul65

Comment: @PedroLobito put your code into an answer please.

Comment: You should probably keep in mind, Python is sort of the anti-Perl in terms of philosophy/language design.

Answer (score 1):

`global` declares the variable to be linked to identically-named variables outside this context for the purposes of changing its value.  You have done this for `func1`, but not for `func2`.

Since `func2` alters a variable `aaa` that is *not* declared `global`, that must be a local variable.  When you try to reference your local `aaa` in the `if` statement, you get the indicated run-time error.

In your later example, where `func2` does *not* change `aaa`, the reference `print(aaa)` is quite legal.  Since there's no local `aaa`, Python searches in the next context outward, and finds the global `aaa` declared by `func1`.

Comment: Just so I understand, my thought was that by making a variable global, it could be shared & manipulated in any of the sub routines of my code; not merely referable. But it appears that you're saying that because I am changing the value of the variable, it must be declared to be global. That the global variable that is being shared is one with a set value, Is this correct?

Comment: Previously I have coded in Perl & if you don't specify "use strict", a variable is available and alterable anywhere in your code or defining a variable with "our" would give the variable a global ability to be defined & altered as required.

Comment: @Paul65 the rule is simple, binding to a name anywhere in a local scope will cause the compiler to mark that variable as *local unless you use the `global` statement*. Merely *accessing* a variable will use the normal scope resolution to try to find it before raising a `NameError`, so local, global, enclosing, built-ins...